# Python setup : command not found

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Apologies if this is a basic question:

I have been trying to setup Python on my laptop by following the tutorial [here](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows). Under *PIP, VIRTUALENV + VIRTUALENVWRAPPER* subtitle, it says

1. And now setup virtualenvwrapper:

   ```
   1 $ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

   2 $ export MSYS_HOME=/c/msys/1.0

   3 $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```

The last line of above gives me the following error:

```
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
sh.exe": /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

So when I test my setup I get the following error:

```
$ mkvirtualenv TestEnv
sh.exe": mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Could some1 help me out please?

THis is all on a Win7 laptop.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install `virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: Yep. I did pip install virtualenvwrapper. When i do it again, I get a msg saying Requirement already satisfied. SO I am assuming that it is installed correctly.

Comment: What is the output of `pip show -f virtualenvwrapper | grep virtualenvwrapper.sh`?

Comment: I just get this: 
    $ pip show -f virtualenvwrapper | grep v
    ..\..\..\Scripts\virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what you wrote it looks to me that you are mixing Windows and Linux shell commands.

I strongly advocate you get the [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) working first before you turn to a wrapper

To get virtualenv on Windows 7

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then

```
virtualenv name_to_your_env

name_to_your_env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: For the second part, I get the following error:

    $ nameOfEnv\bin\activate
    sh.exe": nameOfEnvbinactivate: command not found

Comment: Did you run on on windows command line? "$" at the start which I have just noticed suggests the you are running some shell that you did not mention directly in the question. The command should be run directly in the windows command line

Comment: Iccc! THank you sooo much! Yep that works! SO every time i create a virtual env, I have to do  name_to_your_env\Scripts\activate ? THanks.

Comment: Yea I was running in the shell because in the tutorial i was following here http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows , all the commands began with a $

Comment: Yes, as far as virtualenv is concerned, you have to run it once for every virtual environment you create. Happy that it worked for you.

Comment: The issue may persist when using git bash. Switch to the native command prompt

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem but got it to work a different way in Windows.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv

.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

The key here is running activate.bat rather than just activate. Once I did this and closed and opened cmd again and tried the normal

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

it worked. I don't know why but it worked for me, hopefully it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment, `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is not in `/usr/local/bin`.

You should pass correct path to `source` command.

```
source /path/to/..../Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: I get this when I do the above: '$ source /path/to/..../Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
sh.exe": /path/to/..../Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory'

Comment: @Hasnain, `/path/to/..../Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh` is just a example. You should specify real path.

Comment: Oh I see! Apologies. Where can i find the real path? Thanks.

Comment: @Hasnain, Try `python -c "import os; print os.path.abspath('..\..\..\Scripts\virtualenvwrapper.sh')"` in the directory where you did run the `pip show ...` command. It will tell you absolute path of the shell script.

Comment: Hi, I believe it is c:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh. So i did source c:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh. I still get 


$ source c:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
sh.exe": mktemp: command not found
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered with the same problem and solved it by downloading `mktemp binary` for windows and uncompressing it under git/bin. Then it works. (I was trying to run `leiningen` [lein help] command under Git Bash, on Windows 7)

This is the [download site](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/mktemp.htm) i visited.