# sh.exe no such file or directory Python, GitBash

Tags: python, git, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I trying to setup virtualenvwrapper in GitBash (Windows 7), but get an error message "sh.exe"no such file or directory. 
I wrote in Bash next lines:

```
1 $ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
2 $ export MSYS_HOME=/c/msys/1.0
3 $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And the last line give me an error:

```
 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 sh.exe: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I use for helping this post:[Python setup : command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684231/python-setup-command-not-found). When I run virtualenvwrapper in command line all works, but in GitBash not.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` on your hard drive, and instead of `/usr/local/bin/`, specify the correct directory name.

Comment: I write instead of `/usr/local/bin` the name of folder, where is `virtualenvwrapper.sh`. On my computer it's `/c/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and i get the next message about error: `$ source /c/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh  sh.exe":mktemp:command not found ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name`

Comment: This is another error, please ask it as a separate question on Stack Overflow. (A hint: maybe `export TMPDIR=/c/windows/temp` or something would work.)