# mkvirtualenv: command not found Git Bash Windows

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm following the Django [installation tutorial for Windows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/windows/). I ran the installation command below and it worked fine.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

However, when I try running `mkvirtualenv myproject` I get an error saying `bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

I am running Git Bash on Windows. I found a solution for the Windows Command Prompt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684231/python-setup-command-not-found), but I was hoping to use Git Bash, because I'm much more familiar with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late to answer this, but let me put my anser here anyhow.

I ran the pip install command twice, and finally everything is working for me. Just run "pip install" line this:

First do it: "pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper"
Second, do it: "pip install virtualenvwrapper-win"

Everything should be fine after that.